# How to use a value from one method to other?

Tags: java, android, textview

So i was developing a `bmi` calculator activity in android studio. And i ran into  a problem where i got a value of two variable inside from two methods for different `TextView` which was defined in the class. That shouldn't be problem but once i switch to another `TextView` in app. The first one sends a zero value, which is the problem, Anyone knows how to fix it? Thanks !

The two methods in onCreate which give value:

```
inheight.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    height = Double.parseDouble(inheight.getText().toString());

                if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL== keyCode)
                {
                    if(inheight.getText().length() != 0)
                        inheight.setText(inheight.getText().subSequence(0,inheight.getText().length()-1));
                }

                return true;
            }
        });




        inweight.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    weight = Integer.parseInt(inweight.getText().toString());

                if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL == keyCode)
                {
                    if(inweight.getText().length() != 0)
                    inweight.setText(inweight.getText().subSequence(0,inweight.getText().length()-1));
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

And the Calculate method where i try to calulate

```
    public void calculate()
    {

        if(height!=0 && weight !=0)
       {
// do this
       }
else
{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error: Values Cannot Be Zero!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

So when i run it always shows the toast message :(. Please Help!

Comment: The [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) can be used to catch changes in an `EditText` realtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener),  View.OnKeyListener is useful only for hardware keyboards , and a software input method (like the one android uses), has no obligation to trigger this listener.

So instead of using View.OnKeyListener to get your values i would try a different approach (i.e getting the values after pressing a button, implementing View.OnClickListener )

Also are you sure that only the first TextView gives you the zero value, or both ?

Comment: Thanks for a quick respond, i will try to look  out, and update you on the porblem @Jhon